# HTML in a new window

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new window (or tab), and put html code in it. How can I do that?

Something like:

```
window.open("","foo");
foo.body="alert('HI')';";
```

Comment: Open the window on which event? onClick? onLoad? other?

Comment: Does it matter? Let's say `onload`.

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo What difference does it make to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good old DOM0:

```
var win = window.open("javascript:void(0)");
win.document.write("<html><body>text</body></html>");
win.document.close();
```

Comment: I don't really know this API, why do you do `win.document.close();`?

Comment: Because at the time you call `document.write()` document is already in closed state, but that method will open it again - if you leave at opened state you might encounter some browser-specific bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.open('foo.html', 'foo');
```

and inside `foo.html` you could put the code you wish. For example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This is Foo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('HI')';
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

You could also directly write to the contents of a newly opened window:

```
var win = window.open('', 'foo');
var doc = win.document;
doc.write('<html>');
doc.write('<head>');
doc.write('<title>This is foo</title>');
doc.write('<script type="text/javascript">alert("HI");</script>');
doc.write('</head>')
doc.write('<body>')
doc.write("</body>")
doc.write("</html>")
```

Comment: Yes, but I have already the html code loaded. It would be better for the user not to re-download the content.

Comment: What content? If you already know how to generate the content then simply open a new window and write to the document. If not you could fetch it from the server.

Comment: I have for example `alert('HI');` in window 1 in a variable. And I want to open a window 2 which contains `alert('HI');`.

Comment: What prevents you? Open a new window and write to the document. I've updated my answer to show an example.

Comment: I didn't know how to do it. That's what I was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function openWindow()
 {
     NewWindow=window.open("", "awindow","width=300,height=300");
     NewWindow.document.write('New content...');
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:openWindow()">Open</a>​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/BMm9a/4/)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't can't call a function in child from parent - but you can call a parent function from child

So define a function in the global scope of parent window that returns the desired value:

```
// Parent window
var getHTML = function(){
   return "<span>foo</span>";
};
```

Then call it in child window:

```
// Child window
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('foo').innerHTML = window.opener.getHTML();
};
```